# REACT.JS CONTEXT API - Element type is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am trying to use the react context API but I keep running into this error... I have cross-  checked   my import statements and also checked for types but not finding anything leading to the      error...Please help!
I have provided a snapshot of my context-provider and my index.js where i am making use of it as             well as my app.js

```
DATECONTEXT.JS======================
import { useReducer } from "react";
import Context from "./Context.js";

const defaultValues = {
  defaultDay: 0,
  day: 23,
  month: 8,
  year: 2020,
};

const userReducerFunction = (action, state) => {
  if (action.type === "DAY") console.log("action day received");
  if (action.type === "MONTH") console.log("action Month received");
 if (action.type === "YEAR") console.log("action year received");
  else {
    return state;
  }
};

const DateContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [initialValues, dispatchAction] = useReducer(
    userReducerFunction,
    defaultValues
 );
  const dayHandler = (day) => {
    dispatchAction({ type: "DAY", day });
  };
  const monthHandler = (month) => {
    dispatchAction({ type: "MONTH", month });
  };
  const yearHandler = (year) => {
    dispatchAction({ type: "YEAR", year });
  };

  const contextValues = {
    defaultDay: initialValues.defaultDay,
    day: dayHandler,
    month: monthHandler,
    year: yearHandler,
  };
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={contextValues}>{props.children}</Context.Provider>
  );
};

export default DateContextProvider;


INDEX.JS ==================================================================================

import React from "react";
ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import DateContextProvider from "./components/store/DateContextProvider";

import App from "./App";
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <DateContextProvider>
    <App />
  </DateContextProvider>
);

APP.JS =====================================================================================

import Main from "./components/Main";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Main />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

PACKAGE.JSON=========================================================================

{
  "name": "age-calculator",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.66.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },`your text`
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}

DISPLAY.JS (where I am consuming the useContext hook)==========================

import classes from "./Display.module.scss";
import { useContext } from "react";
import Context from "./store/Context";

const Display = () => {
  const userAgeContext = useContext(Context);
  const day = userAgeContext.defaultDay;
  return (
    <div>
      <div className={classes.display}>
        <div>
          <i>
           <span>38</span>years
          </i>
        </div>
        <div>
         <i>
            <span>{day}</span>months
          </i>
        </div>
        <div>
           <i>
            <span>--</span>days
          </i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Display;



I tried using the React context API but ended up with uncaught run time errors as described above..
```